# Google Apps Script - Time-driven installable triggers - higher frequency than a minute?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need an installable trigger in a form

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onTrigger')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
```

to be triggered every 30 seconds.
Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple options, but if the timing has to be exact it may never be reliable.

You could publish a the script as a web app, then use an external service (CRON on an external server, for example) to hit the published URL every 30 seconds.

EG:

```
function doGet(){
    onTrigger();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('success');
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app

Or you could use Utilities.sleep() and a loop in your code. Something like this:

```
function onTrigger(){
  for(var i = 0; i<2; i++){
     /* 
        your 
        existing 
        code 
        here 
     */

    Utilities.sleep(30000);
  }

}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)

Comment: I'm to "junior" to upvote, so I'll break the commenting rules and thank you! The sleep function should work.

Comment: The for loop will only work for 5 minutes and then exceed max execution time (and fail).

Comment: @Sergeinsas, it only loops twice.

Comment: Ooops, right... sorry, didn't read well enough ;-) and didn't catch you were keeping the original 1 minute trigger.(upvoted to compensate for my silly comment.)